# Bounds on non-Gaussian channels with additive noise

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, information-theory

I am trying to show that for independent random variables $X,Z$ and gaussian independent random variables $X^*,Z^*$, where $Var(X)=Var(X^*)=P$ and $Var(Z)=Var(Z^*)=N$ we have the inequality.
$$
I(X;X+Z^*) \leq I(X^*;X^*+Z^*)\leq I(X^*;X^*+Z)
$$

I can show the first inequality as
$$
\begin{align}
I(X;X+Z^*) &= h(X+Z^*) + h(X+Z^*|X)\\
&= h(X+Z^*) + h(Z^*)\\
&\leq h(X^*+Z^*) + h(Z^*)\\
&= I(X^*;X^*+Z^*)
\end{align}
$$
Where the inequality is because the gaussian is the maximum entropy distribution with a covariance constraint. And because $X\perp Z^*$, $Var(X+Z^*)=P+N$ which is constant, so the maximizing distribution $\tilde X+Z^*$ is gaussian implying $\tilde X = X^*$.

But I'm having trouble proving the second half of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$
I(X^*;X^*+Z)=h(X^*)-h(X^*|X^*+Z)
$$

and note that the entropy $h(X^*|X^*+Z)$ is maximized when $X^*$ conditioned on $X^*+Z$ is Gaussian, which can be the case when $X^*$ and $X^*+Z$ are jointly Gaussian, which, in turn, can be the case when $Z$ is Gaussian.

Comment: I found a proof in this paper http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/51a5/30d8be62e20b5194812f333bd106c445049c.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm2z2gjAmn3jtX06pIyHKiBiw9IuJg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr, that is a bit unsatisfying. I like your intuitive approach, but I've struggled to find a similarly concise but rigorous proof.